# Custom textbox and Custom property with options

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Custom Textbox and I want to create a custom property. I create a custom property that can be seen in the textbox property in the design mode. How to create that custom property like a combobox that have options? Example is like setting up the TextAlign Property it has 3 options like Left, Right and Center. Thanks.

Comment: Create a new class the inherits the Textbox.  Then add additional features to the new class.  Codeprojects have lots of actual code that creates custom c# forms. I've recommended there custom calendars and custom comboboxes many times before.  Best way of finding these projects is to use google with a search like : codeproject c# custom calendar.  It is easier to find these project on google than using the codeproject search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create that custom property like a combobox that have options?
>   Example is like setting up the TextAlign Property it has 3 options
>   like Left, Right and Center.

That's accomplished via a Property with an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) type:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{

    public enum CustomOptions
    {
        Option1,
        Option2,
        Option3
    }

    private CustomOptions _CustomOption = CustomOptions.Option1;

    public CustomOptions CustomOption
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomOption;
        }
        set
        {
            _CustomOption = value;
            switch(_CustomOption)
            {
                case CustomOptions.Option1:
                    TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case CustomOptions.Option2:
                    TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                case CustomOptions.Option3:
                    TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks Idle_Mind. It works! I am using the enum and the one I missed is the get and set. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello, how to get the value of the property? Its always getting Option1 even if I set Option2 in design mode. `public CustomTextBox() : base()
        {
            switch (CustomOption)
            {
                case CustomOptions.Option1:
                    //some code
                    break;
                case CustomOptions.Option2:
                    //some code
                    break;
                case CustomOptions.Option3:
                    //some code
                    break;
            }
        }`

Comment: That's the **constructor**, which only gets called once when the control is created.  Of course it will only be Option1 there because that is what I set the default value to.  If you access the CustomOption property from a different place then you should get the correct, current value...

Comment: Thanks @Idle_Mind, i really appreciate your effort in answering my queries. One thing, I would like to set that if I choose Option2 in design mode then it will automatically set other properties like for example textalign=Right, ForeColor=Color.black. If I choose Option3 textalign=Left, ForeColor=Color.blue. Where will I put the switch case?

Comment: You'd modify the setter in your CustomOption property so that it changes the other desired properties.  I'll change the code above to show this.  Note that when you make changes like this, sometimes you need to delete existing instances of your UserControl and re-add them to your form after re-building the solution.

Comment: I tried the above code and it works like a charm. Thanks you you so much for the help @Idle_Mind. You're the man.